# How to distribute and fulfill the height with bootstrap rows?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]
https://codepen.io/guifeliper/pen/QBNjJP/

```
    .row{
    overflow: hidden;
  }

 .row [class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
  }
```

How could I distribute the heights between the elements inside the column 2?

The code above is divided by First column (Amet)/ Second Column (Lorem/Ipsum/Dolor)
We can see is the second column has the same height as the first column, although the inner elements are not following it, it is not distributing their heights because they are also rows. 
So how could I do for the rows fulfil the second column but distributing the height about themselves? 
Or just the last item fulfil the remaining space?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to fill all the gap and distribute the height between rows, although my solution get the last item and fill the gap. 
For Bootstrap 4:

```
.second-column > .row:last-child{
  height:100%;
}
```

For Bootstrap 3:

```
  .second-column > .row:last-child{
    overflow: inherit;
  }
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/guifeliper/full/LBNGLd/)

Answer (score -2):

just add the following to your css :

`.row{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
  }`

Comment: that gets the first item and put it 100%, sadly that is not the answer